# How to separate stock picking in from out in odoo 8

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

In openerp 7 stock_picking was separated in two items, stock_picking_in and stock_picking_out, now they created one item containing both and there's a field containing the type (in or out). I want to have the normal view for "in" items and a totally custom view for "out". Is it possible and how? Thanks.

My picking.py inherit stock.picking and add some fields. I want the
**picking_in_view** to use **stock.picking** default display for the form view and the tree view and I want to change the display for **picking_out_view**. The problem is that when I change the display in **picking_out_view** it also change in **picking_in_view** because it changes the model.

And the biggest problem is that I need to change the many to many field  with **stock.move** for out items but if I do so I need to modify the model and it do for in and out.

Is there a way to do it?

**move.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api, tools
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError


class StockMove(models.Model):
    """
    Ajout de champs dans la ligne de commande, et quelques fonctions
    telles que unpack
    """
    _inherit = "stock.move"

    # Le code du produit à afficher
    product_code = fields.Char(string="Product", store=True, related="product_id.default_code")
    # Le lien vers la ligne d'achat sale.order.line
    sale_line_id = fields.Many2one(string="SaleOrderLine", store=True, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id")
    # Le colis associé à la commande
    stock_quant_package = fields.Many2one('stock.quant.package', string='Pack')

    # Sert à savoir si on affiche l'icône rouge pour déballer un colis
    show_unpack = fields.Boolean(store=False, compute='compute_show_unpack')
    # Sert à savoir si on affiche l'icône d'impression validée
    is_printed = fields.Boolean(store=False, compute='compute_printed')
    # Pour colorer les lignes, condition
    statut_ok = fields.Boolean(default=False, store=False, compute="compute_statut_ok")

    # Le statut de la commande
    statut_id = fields.Many2one('sale.statut', string='Statut', default=lambda self: self._default_statut_id())
    date_emballage = fields.Datetime("Date d'emballage")

    # Champs non enregistrés en BD, utilisés pour l'affichage
    metal = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Metal", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.metal")
    bois1 = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Bois 1", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.bois1")
    bois2 = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Bois 2", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.bois2")
    verre = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Verre", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.verre")
    tissu = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Tissu", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.tissu")
    patte = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Patte", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.patte")
    config = fields.Char(string="Config", store=False, size=64, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.config")
    poignee = fields.Many2one('product.finition',string="Poignee", store=False, related="procurement_id.sale_line_id.poignee")

    # Le prix d'une ligne de commande, calculé
    move_price = fields.Float(string="Prix", store=False, compute="compute_move_price")

    # Pour differencier les formulaires
    is_picking_out = fields.Boolean(store=False, compute="compute_is_picking_out")

    ...
```

**picking.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api, tools


class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = "stock.picking"

    # Le statut
    statut_id = fields.Many2one("sale.statut", string="Statut")

    # Erreur inconnue sur l'inexistence de ce champ; à laisser
    stock_journal_id = fields.Integer()

    carrier_id = fields.Many2one("stock.carrier", compute="_carrier_info")
    num_compte_transport = fields.Char(string="Numéro de compte UPS", compute="_carrier_info")
    @api.multi
    def _carrier_info(self):
        for line in self:
            line.carrier_id = self.sale_id.carrier_transport
            line.num_compte_transport = self.sale_id.num_compte_facture
```

**picking_in_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- On cache un attribut de la liste des bons de livraison -->
        <record id="stock_picking_tree_view_cr" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.tree.inherit.cr</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='location_dest_id']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Les boutons de modification de la commande de base par Odoo dans le formulaire -->
        <!-- Des bons de livraison -->
        <record id="stock_picking_form_view_cr" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.form.inherit.cr</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='action_assign']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">0</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='force_assign']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">0</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='action_cancel']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">0</attribute>
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - ACTIONS - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- L'action du bouton dans le menu lateral -->
        <record id="picking_in_action_createch" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Bons de réception</field>
            <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">
                [('picking_type_id','=',1)]
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - MENUS - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- Le premier bouton dans la barre laterale -->
        <menuitem id="picking_orders_menu" name="Bons de réception"
                  sequence="0"
                  parent="warehouse_mgt_cr"
                  action="picking_in_action_createch"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**picking_out_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!-- Liste des colis -->
        <record id="stock_quant_package_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.quant.package.tree.cr</field>
            <field name="model">stock.quant.package</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <tree string="Paquets">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="order_name"/>
                    <field name="item"/>
                    <field name="owner_name"/>
                    <field name="create_date"/>
                    <field name="prix" sum="Total Amount"/>
                </tree>

            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- On cache un attribut de la liste des bons de livraison -->
        <record id="stock_picking_tree_view_cr" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.tree.inherit.cr</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='location_dest_id']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Les boutons de modification de la commande de base par Odoo dans le formulaire -->
        <!-- Des bons de livraison -->
        <record id="stock_picking_form_view_cr" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">stock.picking.form.inherit.cr</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="2"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='action_assign']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='force_assign']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='action_cancel']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>

            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - ACTIONS - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- L'action du bouton dans le menu lateral -->
        <record id="picking_action_createch" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Bons de livraison</field>
            <field name="res_model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">
                [('picking_type_id','=',2)]
            </field>
            <field name="context">{"search_default_filter_a_emballer":1}</field>
        </record>

        <!-- Un autre bouton dans la barre laterale. Sert de test actuellement -->
        <record id="stock_quant_package_action_createch" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Colis</field>
            <field name="res_model">stock.quant.package</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>


        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - MENUS - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

        <!-- Le titre dans la barre laterale -->
        <menuitem id="warehouse_mgt_cr" name="Warehouse Management"
                  sequence="0"
                  parent="stock.menu_stock_root"/>

        <!-- Le premier bouton dans la barre laterale -->
        <menuitem id="delivery_orders_menu" name="Bons de livraison"
                  sequence="1"
                  parent="warehouse_mgt_cr"
                  action="picking_action_createch"/>
        <menuitem id="quant_package_colis_menu" name="Colis"
                  sequence="3"
                  parent="warehouse_mgt_cr"
                  action="stock_quant_package_action_createch"/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve is to use `attrs` and based on picking type hide or show fields, if you want to make minor changes, for whole document its not a best solution.

Second way is to create different views for them but only if you are using different menuitems for opening this objects, on the action attached on the menuitem you can specify form and tree views by id, like this example:

```
    <record id="action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Action</field>
        <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field> 
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="action_id_tree">
        <field name="sequence" eval="5"/>
        <field name="view_mode">tree_sent_grievances</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="tree_view_id"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_id"/>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="action_id_form">
        <field name="sequence" eval="5"/>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="form_view_id"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_id"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: I tried to create two different menu items and two different actions but when I modify one form view it modify the parent model so the other take the same appearance, is there a way to modify the form view just for one?

Comment: with the solution what i gave you, you can create two different form and two different tree and use them in the two different actions without any problem, if you have some specific problem i must see a code

Comment: I added more informations about my problem and I added my code if you want to take a look.

Comment: I already did that but when I modify one form view it modify both

Comment: You have everything to get job done, sorry but I wont write code for you

Comment: I don't want you to write code for me, I just want to understand how to modify one form without modifying the other if they both have the same model.

Comment: dude you are using inherit, that means you are changing parent view from child, you should read docs first before going to ask questions to stackoverflow. just take and create another tree view (omg). you dont need to inherit, so you have two tree view and using method i told you, you can assign them to different actions. thats all the logic you need